# How do I print only the values of a table which do not exist into another table - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my SQL database I have a table namend "orders". As you can see the people ordered "cat", "dog" and "frog":

```
id | name 
---------
1  | cat   
2  | dog  
3  | frog
```

I can print my orders like this:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC';

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo($row['name'].' ');
}
```

and get the result: cat dog frog

Now I have another table with my inventory named "inventory":

```
id | name 
---------
1  | cat   
2  | dog  
3  | frog    
4  | duck
```

I have a selectbox on my website, which shows my inventory

```
<select name="animals">

<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY id DESC';

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo('<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>');
}                   
?>
</select>
```

What I want to do now is inside my select box show ONLY the inventory which is not in my orders table.
That means in this case my select box should only have the option "duck".

How do I have to change my selectbox to achieve what I need.

Comment: I think it's best if you read up on normalizing databases.

Comment: Thank you, what does "normalizing database" mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add subselect to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM orders) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution would be to use UNION ALL and check which names just appear once

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
  SELECT tableOrdered.name
  FROM tableOrdered
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TableInventory.name
  FROM TableInventory
)t
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY name
```